# How to put data in an image file (jpeg)?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to allow users to add information to an image that will eventually be saved as a jpeg file. More specifically, I made a flyer and want to allow users to add data to specific areas of it. When the user clicks a submit button, the image should be saved in a jpeg format at a specific path.

How would I go about performing this operation in Android?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code? If so, provide it. Otherwise, this question will likely get downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: What do you want us to do ? write the code for you ?! Maybe we can also write a proper question for you.

Comment: i want the code for the above question because i have no idea how to do the the above task :$